# Why does one specific URL fail with htaccess mod_rewrite redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess contains:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ss

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

On clicking links for, or entering directly into the address bar, all of the following URLs, the result is that the address bar shows the same URL as was keyed in, and the code base processes the index.php page with the 'page' GET parameter (as expected):

- //localhost/ss/help
- //localhost/ss/help2
- //localhost/ss/something
- //localhost/ss/ss
- //localhost/ss/sits

But the following URL has a different result. This URL:

- //localhost/ss/sites

Results in the address bar displaying:

http://localhost/ss/sites/?page=sites

... however, it has still processed the index.php page with the GET parameter correctly. (The page styling is broken now because the link to the CSS is relative - and the presence of the "/sites/" node in the URL path breaks it.

What gives?

After turning on debug logging for mod_rewrite I then went through the steps of going to the following 3 URLs:

- //localhost/ss/
- //localhost/ss/help
- //localhost/ss/sites

Below is a screen capture of the logging information. After that I explain the things I can see in the log file - I have put a letter next to each item in the screenshot.

[image]

- A = lines relating to path /
- B = lines relating to path /help
- C = lines relating to path /sites
- D = verify we are looking at path /help
- E = verify we are looking at path /sites
- F = last line for /help that is in common with processing for /sites
- G = corresponding last line for /sites that is in common with /help
- H = first block of lines for /help that are in common with /sites again
- I = first block of lines for /sites that are in common with /help again
- J = additional lines seen only when processing /sites
- K = seemingly erroneous line - why would args show "page=sites&page=sites"?

Hopefully the log file helps.

Comment: did you clear cache in your browser?

Comment: I don't think that's the issue - I have updated the post to include error log information for debugging mod_rewrite that suggests /sites is processed differently to /help - that should have nothing to do with browser cache.